# How to get the value of a textview in a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I need to get the value of a TextView which is in a certain position of my ListView. How to do it?

**MyJava Code:**

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    TextView txtTechCharacteristic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.techCharacteristic);
    TextView txtTechCharacteristicName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.techCharacteristicName);
}
```

Here Are my TextView ->.

### Layout ListView:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/simple_back_action_bar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Layout Rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/techCharacteristic"         
android:textSize="20sp"         
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/techCharacteristicName"         
android:textSize="15sp"               
android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The code to fill the listView is done within the asynchronous method.Here it is:

```
public class PopulateTechCharacteristicList extends
        AsyncTask<Integer, String, Integer> {

    ProgressDialog progress;
    Context context;

    public PopulateTechCharacteristicList(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(TechCharacteristicList.this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.Wait), getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.LoadingOperations));
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... paramss) {

        ArrayList<TechCharacteristic> arrayTechChar = new ArrayList<TechCharacteristic>();
        TechCharacteristicWSQueries techCharWSQueries = new TechCharacteristicWSQueries();

        try {
            arrayTechChar = techCharWSQueries
                    .selectTechCharacteristicByAsset(asset);

            for (TechCharacteristic strAux : arrayTechChar) {
                HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp.put("cod", strAux.getTechCharacteristic() + " - "
                        + strAux.getTechCharacteristicName());
                temp.put("value",
                        "Valor: " + strAux.getTechCharacteristicValue());
                list.add(temp);
            }

        } catch (QueryException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        if (result == 1) {
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    TechCharacteristicList.this, list,
                    R.layout.techcharacteristic_rows, new String[] { "cod",
                            "value" }, new int[] { R.id.techCharacteristic,
                            R.id.techCharacteristicName });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

onclick already passes the parent view as "v"

Just use

```
TextView txtTechCharacteristic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.techCharacteristic);
String txt = txtTechCharacteristic.getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onListItemClick()
```

Get list (server response) object reference then get data at item click from `position` index.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
View view = (View)v.getParent();  
TextView txtTechCharacteristic = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.techCharacteristic);
TextView txtTechCharacteristicName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.techCharacteristicName);
}
```

Use `getText()` to get the text from textview's.

Comment: It did not work. He continues taking the value of the first list item.

Comment: @user1792343 post your listview layout xml with which its not possible to give you a proper answer what does continues taking value of the first list item mean?

Comment: @user1792343 what it looks to me it should work. i can't think any other reason. good luck if someone else can find the right answer for you

Comment: @user1792343 It does not work due to your list creation put adapter code here

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find for your text view through the ListViews selected items parentGroup view that is the argument **View v**

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(v!=null)
    {
    TextView txtTechCharacteristic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.techCharacteristic);
    TextView txtTechCharacteristicName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.techCharacteristicName);
    }
}
```

Comment: My list of items carries as the result of a select DB. Depending on the outcome, I have several items, making my textView (techCharacteristic techCharacteristicName ae) multiply. When I instantiate my control textview, I can not get the exact value clicked.

Comment: yes you will have to change your list creation put your adapter code here

Answer (score 0):

A listview recycles its view when you scroll down and re uses its views. I will not store the details of previous views in memory. Better you can keep you data in an arraylist or array and then in `onListItemClick` method get the position and get the data from that position of arraylist/array